# Cross entropy loss starts out very low

Tags: nlp, training, transformer, attention-mechanism

I'm working on making a transformer from scratch as described in the "Attention is All You Need" Paper. When training my model, my cross-entropy loss is always very low at the start. For example, my first epoch saw a loss of 8.16e-5. Is it normal for Cross Entropy loss to be this low right from the start?